# What would happen if two super-massive black holes collide faster than the speed of light?

Tags: black-holes, space-expansion, collision, faster-than-light

I know objects can't move through space faster than light. But there's no law against the expansion of the universe increasing the distance between two objects faster than the speed of light. But this should also mean that if the process got reversed, then the distance between two galaxies could decrease faster than the speed of light and at some point the super-massive black holes in their centers could also collide faster than the speed of light. Right? What would happen then?

Answer (score 4):

That can't happen. The cosmological speeds that can exceed $c$ aren't measured in the same way as the local speeds that don't exceed $c$. Nearby objects never have a superluminal relative velocity no matter how large (and negative) the Hubble constant may be.

Comment: Two ordinary objects cannot collide faster than light indeed. However, the coordinate speed of light near a black hole is asymptotically zero at the horizon. In this sense any two black holes always collide faster than the speed of light near their horizons. Your answer is correct only for ordinary objects, but not for black holes where the concept of “local” has a very different meaning.

Comment: @safesphere can you give a reference to your claim, to educate us? what is coordinate speed of light ?

Comment: @annav “Coordinate speed” in the Schwarzschild solution usually refers to the speed measured in the Schwarzschild coordinates. Due to the time dilation near the horizon, everything there moves slower, including light, as observed from afar. The behavior of light is described by the Schwarzschild metric with $\tau=0$. For radial light $$(1-r_s/r)dt^2-(1-r_s/r)^{-1}dr^2=0$$ and from this the coordinate speed of light is $dr/dt=1-r_s/r$ which is zero at the horizon.